# A construction that sort of merges two semigroups to build a new one

Tags: reference-request, semigroups-and-monoids

Suppose $H$ and $K$ are semigroups and assume without loss of generality that (the underlying sets of) $H$ and $K$ are disjoint. We can then extend the operations of both $H$ and $K$ to a binary operation $\cdot$ on $H \cup K$ by taking $x \cdot y = y \cdot x := y$ for all $x \in H$ and $y \in K$. Let me provisionally denote the magma obtained in this way by $H \oslash K$. It is easy to check that (i) $H \oslash K$ is a semigroup (i.e., the operation $\cdot$ is associative) and (ii) if $H$ is a monoid (i.e., a semigroup with identity), then so is $H \oslash K$ (the identity of $H \oslash K$ being the same as the identity of $H$).

**Question.** Does the above construction have a name? Is it a special case of a more general construction that I'm not recognizing? Is there a (more or less) standard notation for the object that I'm denoting by $H \oslash K$?

Comment: Using semidirect product notation for this is horrible since semidirect product of semigroups makes sense and many people use the symbol for that.

Comment: This is a special case of an ideal extension.  I'm not sure this particular case has a name

Comment: If $S$ and $T$ are semigroups and you have a homomorphism from $S$ into the translational hull of $T$ you can make $S\cup T$ as semigroup with $T$ an ideal. Your homomorphism is just the trivial homomorphism into the translational hull.  In Clifford and Preston you can find a more general construction where S is a semigroup with 0 and the product of two elements of S is allowed to be an element of T if the product is 0 on S

Comment: I had one paper where I called this the join.  But that was for a particular class of semigroups which are ordered and the poset if the new semigroup was the join of the poset of the two factors.  But I don't think that is a good name in general

Comment: I totally agree that the semidirect product notation was horrible. Just wanted to have an asymmetric symbol and picked the first thing that came to my mind (I'm now using ⊘
). Which paper of yours are you referring to in your last message? Can you provide a link or a more precise reference?

Comment: I might call this a "trivial ideal extension" (following the terminology explained by Benjamin Steinberg).

Comment: I think trivial ideal extension is ok. The arXiv version is https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05446 page 16.  But I think join is only appropriate in our context because our semigroups were face posets of cw complexes in the paper and this corresponded to joins of the corresponding cw complexes (I’m over simplifying)

Comment: "Trivial ideal extension (of K by H)" sounds good to me too. In particular, the "unconditional unitization" of a semigroup K becomes the trivial ideal extension of K
 by the trivial group whose underlying set is {K} (here, "unconditional" means that we add an identity regardless of whether K
 is already unital), and the trivial extension of K by a group H is a monoid whose group of units is H. In case anyone is willing to summarize the previous comments in an answer, I'll accept it in such a way that the thread is marked as answered.